# Tag guidance for using [icc] vs [international-court]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-renaming

I noticed the [icc](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/icc) and [international-court](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international-court) are used somewhat interchangeably on recent questions about the ICC warrant for President Putin.

I wonder what the tag guidance should be so these tags are used more consistently. Currently, the descriptions read:

[icc](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/icc):

> The International Criminal Court is an international court established through the Rome Statue that entered into force in 2002. The court investigates and tries crimes against the international community, specifically "genocide, war crimes, crimes against humanity and the crime of aggression".

[international-court](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international-court):

> Questions relating to courts that are formed by treaties between nations. Examples include the International Criminal Court and the Nuremberg Trials.

Comment: Perhaps we should rename the latter tag to "international-court**s**" to make clear that it is not about any international court in particular but rather an umbrella tag for all kinds of international courts.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suggest renaming [icc](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/icc) to [international-criminal-court](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international-criminal-court), dropping the [icc](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/icc) tag.

Add the tag [international-court-of-justice](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international-court-of-justice) for questions about the ICJ (aka, World Court). Nineteen questions:

- [8 questions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+icj) `is:q icj`
- [9 questions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%22international+court+of+justice%22+-icj) `is:q "international court of justice" -icj`
- [2 questions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%22world+court%22) `is:q "world court"`

Suggested usage:

> Questions about, or actions taken, by the International Court of Justice, also known as the World Court. This court hears civil cases between different countries. For similar questions about criminal cases, see [international-criminal-court]. If your question is not about either of these courts, see [international-courts] for guidance.

As @Philipp suggests, add an `s` to rename [international-court](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international-court) to [international-courts](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international-courts).

Suggested usage update, along with the list of other tags, as shown below, in tag info:

> Questions relating to courts that are formed by treaties between nations. Examples include the International Criminal Court and the International Court of Justice, for which specific tags are available. See the tag info (Learn more...) for additional courts and their tags.

Retag questions for the two specific courts, reserving [international-courts](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international-courts) for general use or courts with no available tag.

This would result in four tags containing `court`.

Following is the tag information added to [international-courts](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international-courts).

---

Additional tags for certain international and regional courts. These tags may be used instead of the [international-courts](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international-courts) tag.

**International Courts and Tribunals**

Universal Jurisdictions:

- [international-court-of-justice](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international-court-of-justice) International Court of Justice
- [international-criminal-court](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international-criminal-court) International Criminal Court
- International Labour Organization Administrative Tribunal
- International Tribunal for the Law of the Sea
- Permanent Court of Arbitration
- [world-bank](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-bank) World Bank - International Centre for the Settlement of Investment Disputes
- [intellectual-property](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intellectual-property) World Intellectual Property Organization Arbitration and Mediation Center.
- [wto](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wto) World Trade Organization Dispute Settlement Body and Appellate Body

Ad Hoc Criminal Tribunals and Special Courts:

- (five items not shown)

Nuremberg War Crimes Trials:

- (five items not shown)

**Regional Courts**

- Caribbean Court of Justice
- Central American Court of Justice
- Court of Justice of the Andean Community
- The Court of Justice of the Common Market for Eastern and Southern Africa (COMESA)
- [european-union](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/european-union) Court of Justice of the European Union
- [osce](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osce) Court on Conciliation and Arbitration - Organization for Security and Cooperation in Europe
- [echr](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/echr) European Court of Human Rights
- [efta](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/efta) European Free Trade Agreement Court
- [council-of-europe](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/council-of-europe) Council of Europe
- Inter-American Court of Human Rights

This list of courts is from the [US Department of Justice](https://www.justice.gov/jmd/ls/international-courts).

Comment: Thanks, the tag renaming has been done. :)

Comment: By the way, are you sure we don't want to keep [icc] and [icj] as synonyms? They seem unambiguous and make it a lot easier to add tags quickly.

Comment: @JJJ - [icc] and [icj] as synonyms? I suppose we cannot require users to *know* to type `court` to choose among the three tags mentioned here. And, the US Interstate Commerce Commission (ICC) was dissolved in 1996 with no questions on the main site, so maybe there would be no confusion. There are 262 uses of `ICC` listed at https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/ICC. From a US perspective, I can find no strong objection to having [icc] and [icj] as synonyms.

Comment: Thanks for checking so thoroughly. I added those two as synonyms. If it ever turns out to be problematic we can remove the synonyms quite easily.